# removing a class if classname === id

Tags: javascript

I am working on a side-menu. The menu has main categories and sub-categories.

I would like to only show the sub-categories of the active categories.

I am trying to achieve this by adding a class "d-none" (display: none) to all the sub-category elements and then removing the "d-none" class from the appropriate sub-categories. I determine this by ... `if (subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.contains === clicked.id)`, but it doesn't work.

Let say this is my code. console.log(clicked.id) returns the correct value, but "d-none" class doesn't get removed from the appropriate elements.

Any help would be most welcome. Thank you

```
<div class="sub-main" id="one">
    <a href="main-1">Main Category One</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-sub one" id="one-one">
    <a href="main-1-1">Sub One One</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-sub one" id="one-two">
    <a href="main-1-2">Sub One Two</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-sub one" id="one-three">
    <a href="main-1-3">Sub One Three</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-main" id="two">
    <a href="main-2">Main Category Two</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-sub two" id="two-one">
    <a href="main-2-1">Sub Two One</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-sub two" id="two-two">
    <a href="main-2-2">Sub Two Two</a>
</div>
<div class="sub-main" id="three">
    <a href="main-3">Main Category Three</a>
</div>
```

```
function ActiveMain (clicked_id){
    for (let i = 0; i < mainSubCategoryArray.length; i++){
        mainSubCategoryArray[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    var clicked = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    clicked.classList.add("active");

    console.log(clicked);
    console.log(clicked.id);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < subSubCategoryArray.length; i++){
        subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.add("d-none");
        console.log(clicked.id);
        if (subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.contains === clicked.id){
            subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.remove("d-none");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.contains === clicked.id` => `subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.contains(clicked.id)`

Comment: thank you. that did it. Anwser and I'll accept

Comment: Why don't you use event delegation? Your code could be simpler.

Comment: could you give me an example of event delegation from my example? I'd love to simplify it more.

Comment: I would give you an example, but your HTML code should be completely rewritten. For a clear explanation of event delegation, take a look here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation Try to make it on your own. If you need help, ask new question here on SO. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `classList.contains` that is a function with the ID, instead you should do something like this:

```
subSubCategoryArray[i].classList.contains(clicked.id);
```